# Google API Service Account Access Token expires

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, access-token, service-accounts

I want to retrieve [realtime user data from Google Analytics and this article by Google](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) outlines how to this (and works as expected).

```
 gapi.client.analytics.data.realtime.get({
                    "ids": "ga:21660971",
                    "metrics": "rt:activeUsers"
                })
```

However I am following [the server-side authentication](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) because I want this to be always visible to users who do not have access. But overnight this access token has become invalid. What can I do or rework to make this work with the need to constantly have manual intervention to refresh the token all of the time!

**Python script (as is in the Google article).**

```
# service-account.py

import time

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
# The scope for the OAuth2 request.
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

# The location of the key file with the key data.
KEY_FILEPATH = 'MY-JSON-FILE.json'

# Defines a method to get an access token from the ServiceAccount object.
def get_access_token():
  return ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILEPATH, SCOPE).get_access_token().access_token

print(get_access_token())
```

**JS Authentification**

```
    /**
     * Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
     */
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        'serverAuth': {
            'access_token': 'TOKEN-FROM-PY-SCRIPT-ABOVE'
        }
    });
```

This is the error given in the console, and it only does this after 60 minutes or so.

> {domain: "global", reason: "authError", message: "Invalid
>   Credentials", locationType: "header", location: "Authorization"}
>
> Array(0) message
>
> "Invalid Credentials"

Comment: please post the error are you sure  the access token is invalid and not that you have blown out your quota?   Service accounts dont really work with access tokens it should request access when ever you try and hit the api.

Comment: @DaImTo Updated with error messages, definitely token issue. What way would you recommend instead?

Comment: @tim.baker
Hi I am trying to solve the same issue.
were you able to solve the issue?
Could You please help with the approach.

Thanks